# VIM: how to split window to show buffers?

Tags: vim, split, window, buffer

My buffer explorer shows there're 3 opened files. I can use :b n command to switch between buffers. But I wish to open all 3 buffers in split windows.

(1) Is there a command to do this?

(2) If I wish to close one of these 3 split windows, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

▶ To open 3 buffers each one in a winodw:

- `vim -o3 file1 file2 file3`
- `:ball`
- `vim -O3 file1 file2 file3`
- `:vertical ball`

▶  To close a window:

- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>
- `:wincmd q`
- `:q!`
- `:close!`